# Replace a specific file in a zip using java

Tags: java, file, replace, zip

I need to replace a specific CSS file inside zip archive the file is stored under folders EPUB/styles/stylesheet.css

here is my code(I need to do it in java 6)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File newCss=new File("D:\\test\\css\\stylesheet.css");
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream
    (new File("D:\\test\\css\\edited\\my_book.epub"),true));
    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("EPUB/styles/stylesheet.css"));

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(newCss);
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096 * 1024]; 
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    out.closeEntry();
    in.close();
    out.close();
    System.out.println("Done Replacing entry");
}
}
```

but on executing this code the whole zip contains only the CSS i replaced all the other contents are lost but the zip shows  the same size as before, on extracting the zip i get only the file i replaced.

Comment: Do you use Java 7? If yes, there is a much better way of doing that...

Comment: i know there is a way in java 7, but in need to do it in java 6